# Decentralized authentication against Windows domain

Tags: python, windows, authentication, wif, federated-identity

There are many solutions for third-party decentralized authentication that are pretty simple to set up: log in with Facebook credentials, OpenID, OAuth etc.

How can I do something similar inside the firewall, in a Windows domain environment?

The scenario:

- Python web application inside the firewall, hosted on a Linux server.
- Users have Windows desktops and authenticate to a Windows domain

I know I can validate a username/password against Active Directory using LDAP, but that is not what I want. I don't want my app to handle the username/password at all. I want it to work as OpenID does, i.e. my app redirects the user to some sort of Windows identity provider web page.

Is there a out-of-the-box Windows/IIS solution for this?

**EDIT:**

- Could [Windows Identity Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa570351.aspx) be what I'm looking for? Or perhaps WIF has the building blocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the risk of giving too many answers, it sounds to me like [ADFS 2.0](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adfs2%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) is your path of least resistance. As far as integrating claims based access into your python application, I've seen [pysaml2](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysaml2) recommended as a way to do this, but I can't speak from experience.

Comment: I'm not a python guy, so I don't know much about pysaml2 apart from the website I linked. On the ADFS side there is extensive documentation. I don't know if there's any ADFS to python SP specific tutorials out there, but all you should need for ADFS is a guide to show you how to deploy it to run as a SAML2 identity provider. Here's an example: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adfs2-federation-with-ping-identity-ping-federate(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Another interesting link: http://wiki.service-now.com/index.php?title=Configuring_ADFS_2.0_to_Communicate_with_SAML_2.0

Comment: Maybe this library could help? https://github.com/Trondheim-kommune/python-saml-adfs

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a Windows guy, but [Crowd](https://www.atlassian.com/software/crowd/overview) from Atlassian:

- Will run on Windows
- Can authenticate against Active Directory
- Includes an OpenID provider

So if you're application can handle OpenID, you'd have everything you need.

Comment: Looks like Crowd would work. However, there are a couple of things I do not like about it. It is java-based, I would prefer a solution that is easier to integrate into a Windows/IIS environment. An IIS application would be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

WIF together with Azure ACS will provide this out the box. e.g. [Adding a Custom OpenID Provider to ACS… with JUST ONE LINE of PowerShell Code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbertocci/archive/2011/05/19/adding-a-custom-openid-provider-to-acs-with-just-one-line-of-powershell-code.aspx).

Or you could integrate with [Dot Net Open Auth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) either with your own STS or using something like [Identity Server](http://identityserver.codeplex.com/).

Comment: WIF and DotNetOpenAuth are both .NET frameworks so they won't be of much help integrating his python app, unless it's iron python.ACS is an interesting option if he wants to federate his app with multiple identity providers, but it sounds like he just wants internal windows integrated auth.

Comment: Can Azure ACS be installed on an internal Windows server box? Or is it only available on the Azure cloud platform?

Comment: No - only available on the Azure cloud platform. But look at my other suggestions. Both can be installed internally - but they may need external access depending on your use case.